# Click column header

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

I want to order the items in `listview` by the time or payment or name I'm use now the `combobox` but i want to do it from the `listview` header when i clicked on header column  i want the `listview` sorted by it , i'm use this code with the combo box please help me.

[image]

```
Private Sub OrderBy()
    Try
        Dim OB As String
        If ComboBox1.Text = "ID" Then
            OB = "ID"
        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Name" Then
            OB = "StudentName"
        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Payment" Then
            OB = "Payment"
        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Time" Then
            OB = "LessonTime"
        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Date" Then
            OB = "LessonDate"
        End If

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Tend order by " & OB & "", con)
        da.Fill(dt)
        Dim myrow As DataRow
        For Each myrow In dt.Rows
            ListView1.Items.Add(myrow.Item(0))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(1))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(2))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(3))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(4))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(5))
        Next
```

Comment: Consider using the ColumnClick event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columnclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use `e.ColumnIndex` to know the index of column clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explaining better, use the `ColumnClick` event and use `e.Column` to know the index of column that was clicked

EDIT: This isn't the best way to do it, but it is the easiest way for you now.

```
Private Sub OrderBy(Col as Integer)
Try
    Dim OB As String

    Select Case Col
       'Depending on the order of columns in your table
       Case 0
          OB = "ID"
       Case 1
          OB = "StudentName"
       Case 2
          OB  = "Payment"
       Case 3
          OB  = "LessonTime"
       Case 4
          OB  = "LessonDate"
    End Select

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Tend order by " & OB & "", con)
    da.Fill(dt)
    ListView1.Items.Clear
    For Each myrow As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim item = ListView1.Items.Add(myrow.Item(0))
        item.SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(1))
        item.SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(2))
        item.SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(3))
        item.SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(4))
        item.SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(5))
    Next
End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ColumnClick(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As ColumnClickEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ColumnClick
    OrderBy(e.Column)
End Sub
```

Comment: i have problem with the code , error in "ColumnIndex" --> : ColumnIndex not member of 'system.windows.form.ColumnClickEventArgs'

Comment: I have just corrected the name of Property to Column insteacd of ColumnIndex.

Comment: hey @Nizam i cant use this code , how can i know who the column that i choose it and sort the data , i'm use this statement to sort , select * from std order by time , or order by name and so on , please help me i need this to work so bad , thanks a lot

Comment: Ok, the property Column gives you the number of Column clicked starting from zero. The first Column is zero, one and go on. After knowing the Column clicked, you can use your code to sort the data.

Comment: In my answer the variable col represents the number of Column clicked and variable ColumnName references the title of Column clicked.

Comment: thanks a lot @Nizam , yes i know this but i tried to know the column number by when i click on the column the column number appear in textBox1 For example but i don't have any response when i clicked on any column :( can you help me with the code like this

Comment: I have changed the code to make it clearer for you. Any doubts, please call me on chat.

Comment: hey @Nizam i don't know how can i thank you this is amazing man ,,,, really really thanks i wish the best for you :)

Comment: I am very happy that I could help. ;-) the best 4u2

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem, I found a Microsoft tutorial in c# and converted to VB.NET a while back.

You can check out my converted open source project on: http://www.sourcecodester.com/visual-basic-net/5415/how-sort-listview-control-column-header-vbnet.html

It shows how to add new items, separated into columns, and you are able to sort the list view, by clicking on the column header. You can also set the default sort method.

Comment: thanks @nimblebit this is exactly what i want , but i cant use the code , can you put my code in yours it doesn't work with me :( thanks a lot